# How to determine analytically $C(n,k_m,m)$ in ${\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k_{m}}{C{({n,k_{m},m})} \cdot f{(n)}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I started to get curious about the real values the generic sum $F(k)$

$$ F{(k) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}\frac{\cos\left( {b \cdot \ln(q)} \right)}{n^{a}}}} $$

produces, according to $k$, when:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
{q = e^{n}} \\ 
{b = 1} \\
{a = 0}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

In general, related to $F(k)$ above:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{n,k\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}} \\
{a\in \mathbb{R}} \\
{b\in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

$F(k)$, with $q=n$ and $k\rightarrow \infty$, is the real part of the Riemann
Zeta function $\zeta$

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{\zeta{(s) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}}}} \\
{s = {a + \mathit{ib}}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

So, with definitions for $q$, $b$ and $a$ written previously,
$$F{(k) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{\cos(n)}}}$$

If I plot this function for $k$, I noticed (only visually on graph, but
not proved mathematically) that the set of $F(k)$ values seems to be in a
constant range between $1/2$ and $-3/2$.

From this observation, I tried to see if it was possible to find an
analytical function corresponding to $F(k)$. I used a simple approach,
that is the repetition of the following general equality (i.e. by
writing $g1$ as $g2$ and so on)

$$\underset{g2}{\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{f(n)}}} = {{\int\limits_{1}^{k + 1}{f{(x)}\mathit{dx}}} - \underset{g1}{\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}\left\lbrack {{\left( {\int\limits_{n}^{n + 1}{f(x)\mathit{dx}}} \right) - f}{(n)}} \right\rbrack}}}$$

to identify a form that relates $F(k)$ to an analytical formula that has
no summation terms (for example when $g1\rightarrow 0$ for
$k\rightarrow \infty$ or when the two terms $g1$ and $g2$ are simplified after
several attempts in which $g1$ is repeatedly rewritten as $g2$).
Unfortunately I have not been able to obtain a result (e.g. with the
method above I can determine the analytical expression of simpler
summations, e.g. when $f(n)=n^{2}$).

So I used a CAS (in this case the free service provided by Wolfram
Alpha, please do not criticise for this), that gives

$$F{(k) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{\cos(n)}} = \frac{1}{2}}\left( {\cos{(k) + \frac{1}{\tan\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}} \cdot \sin{(k) - 1}} \right)$$

For now I'm not really interested to prove this, but to understand if
there is a general method to define the average value around which the
values of $F(k)$ are distributed for $k\rightarrow \infty$, without at first to
know the ''closed'' analytical form of the summation.

Visually this average value appears to be equal to $-1/2$, and probably it
corresponds to the horizontal axis along which the inflection points of
the analytical expression found with CAS are distributed (again, I can't
prove it, but for now I don't care).

My simple approach was to determine the average of $F(k)$, that is

$$\overline{F}{(k) = \frac{1}{k}}{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{\cos{(n)\cdot\left( {k - n + 1} \right)}}}$$

With this expression I can observe, always graphically and not mathematically, that $\overline{F}(k)$ decreases as
$k$ increases and the points tend to converge towards the horizontal axis
around which the periodic trend of $F(k)$ develops (as average).

**What I am most curious about at the moment**, and that is why I
decided to write here, **is whether there is a direct formula that
provides the coefficients $C(n,k_m,m)$ in case I decide to
determine the average of $F(k)$ for $m$ times as follows**:

$${\overline{F}}_{m}{\left( k_{m} \right) = \frac{1}{k_{m}}}{{\sum\limits_{k_{m - 1} = 1}^{k_{m}}{\frac{1}{k_{m - 1}}{\sum\limits_{k_{m - 2} = 1}^{k_{m - 1}}{\frac{1}{k_{m - 2}}{\sum\limits_{k_{m - 3} = 1}^{k_{m - 2}}{\ldots\frac{1}{k_{1}}{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k_{1}}{f{(n)}{\cdot\left( {k_{1} - n + 1} \right)}}}}}}}}} = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k_{m}}{C{({n,k_{m},m})}\cdot f{(n)}}}}$$

where

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{C\left( {n,k_{m},m} \right)\in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}} \\
{m\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

For example, if $k_m=4$ and $m=2$, I have:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{C{\left( {1,4,2} \right) = 1}} \\
{C{\left( {2,4,2} \right) = \dfrac{161}{576}}} \\
{C{\left( {3,4,2} \right) = \dfrac{23}{288}}} \\
{C{\left( {4,4,2} \right) = \dfrac{1}{64}}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

As another example, if $k_m=5$ and $m=3$, I have:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{C{\left( {1,5,3} \right) = 1}} \\
{C{\left( {2,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{205147}{1080000}}} \\
{C{\left( {3,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{25717}{540000}}} \\
{C{\left( {4,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{433}{40000}}} \\
{C{\left( {5,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{1}{625}}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

So, does exist a direct formula to determine the $n$ coefficients $C$ as a function of the parameters $k_m$ and $m$, or the only way is to perform numerous arithmetic calculations algorithmically, as I simply did in the two examples listed?

Note that $f(n)$ is of no interest in this case, $f(n)=\cos(n)$ was just a practical example with which I started studying the problem with an ''engineering'' approach (i.e. by using computer graphics tools and CAS), certainly not with a rigorous mathematical one.

***EDIT 1***:
I did a trivial error with indexes, sorry. I rewrite:

if $k_m=4$ and $m=2$:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{C{\left( {1,4,2} \right) = 1}} \\
{C{\left( {2,4,2} \right) = \dfrac{23}{48}}} \\
{C{\left( {3,4,2} \right) = \dfrac{5}{24}}} \\
{C{\left( {4,4,2} \right) = \dfrac{1}{16}}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

while if $k_m=5$ and $m=3$:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{C{\left( {1,5,3} \right) = 1}} \\
{C{\left( {2,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{5981}{18000}}} \\
{C{\left( {3,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{1091}{9000}}} \\
{C{\left( {4,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{77}{2000}}} \\
{C{\left( {5,5,3} \right) = \dfrac{1}{125}}} \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

The coefficients $C$ in my first post (before ***EDIT 1***) were for $k_m=4$ with $m=3$ and $k_m=5$ with $m=4$.

In reply to Claude, thank you for demonstrating the average development equal to $-1/2$ of $${\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{\cos(n)}}$$

About coefficients $C$ I have not a direct formula (I don't know if it exists). I did some simple calculations by hand with fractions (and verifying the result with a CAS). I should most probably rewrite the formula for $\overline{F}_{m}{\left( k_{m}\right)}$, I understand that it is unclear, but I could not find another way to write it more clearly, sorry.

For example, if $m=2$ and $k_2=4$ one can write:

$${\overline{F}}_{2}{\left( 4 \right) = \frac{1}{4}}\cdot{{\sum\limits_{k_{1} = 1}^{4}{ \left( \frac{1}{k_{1}}\cdot{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k_{1}}  { \left( f{(n)}{\cdot\left( {k_{1} - n + 1} \right) }\right)}}\right)}}}$$

and with a little patience develops all the terms and simplifies them, obtaining the $C$ coefficients.
So

$${\overline{F}}_{2}{\left( 4 \right) = \frac{1}{4}}\cdot{{\sum\limits_{k_{1} = 1}^{4}{ \left( \frac{1}{k_{1}}\cdot{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k_{1}}  { \left( f{(n)}{\cdot\left( {k_{1} - n + 1} \right) }\right)}}\right)}}} = f(1)+\frac{23}{48}f(2)+\frac{5}{24}f(3)+\frac{1}{16}f(4)$$

To be honest, these are somewhat tedious (not difficult) calculations, so it would certainly be useful to have an algorithm that determines these coefficients for any value of $m$ and $k_m$.
If $k_m$ (in our example $k_2$) is not known, one can have the plottable (for $k_2$) general form

$${\overline{F}}_{2}{\left( k_2 \right) = \frac{1}{k_2}}\cdot{{\sum\limits_{k_{1} = 1}^{k_2}{ \left( \frac{1}{k_{1}}\cdot{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k_{1}}  { \left( f{(n)}{\cdot\left( {k_{1} - n + 1} \right) }\right)}}\right)}}}$$

that is the average of $F(k)$ of ''order'' $2$ ($m=2$). In this general form one will have a number of $C$ coefficients equal to $k_2$ ($C$ depends from $m=2$ and from $k_2$, and generalizing as much as possible $C$ depends from $m$ and $k_m$ and there is a $C$ for each $n$ from $1$ to $k_m$).

My interest is whether this is a problem that cannot be solved with finite formulae but only by performing the calculations with an algorithm that performs simplifications on a variable amount of numbers and fractions in an iterative manner (i.e. with a computational complexity that increases as $k_m$ and $m$ increase), as when averaging a set of numbers, for which there is no other way than to add all the numbers in the set and divide the sum by the cardinality of the set (sorry for this comparison).

***EDIT 2***:
I created a little python script with SageMathCell to see graphically some functions described in original post, in particular the "order 2" average of the real part of $\zeta$. The link is [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJy1lM-vojAQx-8m_g9NnglFESn7zCabkOxl97THvfmDFKxKrIWU-hbX8L_vVCogotnLM0bszLcz00-HSY5ZKhUSp2N2RjRHIhsOksp2pCrjqeJJ5GZn_U_7M66Gg-HgeyIUkzSGxYZtUYgPfpDzZMMkXhDXnXuet3IQuOiJq4DYDqI3_9R3fAflimVhnvxlged680bquXMQRwEm7y758v7Vnzt4OvecuWfb9jedGsEn36d_8C-qWPGjyCSWVhRYaAJBJY5AV4navx8sVqFAAZzP5YnIMxozTJyDD18jb8Rvb2irtXGa42jMBRa2PRNr2grV9qc7XIUHVfVnPKZ9MfPTUW-DB-6GdpAISFNLlcPoF6vKmFGpEspDMIPVlLHwVt0tLs0yJja4pTdht6lEBUoEklTsqvNrprdK7xO0V5M6XbFq9K9Tdq_gRiA8EgPhgYI9hj6aigmxZ3Azz5BUAV5R0aoeMLDxE9lck_bjeZn4QQpB7k5iTDOECyBzewUanL7BSQDa-ClXYrgSw1W_kwfyjLD_H4R1XX2Q_U-GXPHoh_ci94P0kbPf4fxk2CzTDyZhirDLzzL08SH07Xr83IeDbiareiA17wJMUZcWex0Dn_UEdGCY8FQGlrQcpM25OnMWWFOrvnC9R09hM2yc-8rrAHE3ACxpxDgKpDXqqRwQLLcwyS-kvMC6RMt4A6N-ydlWYbSE8CHYoVHKtfEbT7OJ1JuuamG0pKO9dqVRVr1ZXsT6QsuyskE5VZOipUx2e_X4RKMGRwOFs52-cbtrL67nhvsaQd3XnTfPufb0AKmVjX4nkw3-LU-sFePaFa11zLfY_gde7yrJ&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (I don't know if it is possible to directly add that interactive graph here, by embedding the html full code, as described [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/about.html?v=0141c2bee781881e735b5e98a913a0de5f2b2efc011158c7627de0318c02f6cc569f07beefc2eca4bdba7e55ec59235a4ba78ce37797ae52d0978386182bd413), in order to avoid opening links that could be considered suspicious; but it is a question for StackExchange managers).

It is interesting, at least for me, to observe that for Riemann Zeta zeros (i.e. $a=0.5, b=\{14.134725, ...\}$) $\overline{F}_2(k_2)$ seems to develop around the horizontal axis $y=0$, in particular for $a<\frac{1}{2}$ the sum $\overline{F}_2(k_2)$ seems to diverge while for $a>\frac{1}{2}$ the sum $\overline{F}_2(k_2)$ seems to converge, in both cases the average trend seems different from $y=0$ (or $\overline{F}_2(k_2)=0$). I tried only some few Zeta zeros.

Therefore it would occur to me, but it is just a very basic interpretation that makes no use of complex analysis of which I know nothing (I am a mere amateur enthusiast), that only for the zeros of the Riemann Zeta function (i.e., for $a=1/2$ and for some values of $b$, that are infinite) the average of summation $F{(k) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}\frac{\cos\left( {b \cdot \ln(n)} \right)}{n^{a}}}}$ develops around the $y=0$ axis, i.e., the average of infinite order ($m=\infty$) of the infinite values that make up the set formed by the values of $F(k)$ for each $k\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ is a constant value and in particular equal to zero, in all other cases this constant value is non-zero. **Does exist an official proof of this or it is another way (very simplified and not rigorous and probably wrong) to describe the Riemann Hypothesis?**

Comment: At least to me, the notations in the formula following *"for $m$ times as follows"* are not very clear (I am blind and this is not a joke). At the same time, I have the feeling that the problem is interesting. Could you write completely (with explicit numbers) the formula for $k_m=4$ and $m=2$ ?

Comment: In my answer (which is not an answer), I rewrote the formulae to make a few things clearer (at least to me). If you want to use them in your post, jus do it and I should delete my junk later.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you for reply about average trend of ${\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{\cos(n)}}$. I also updated my post (**EDIT 1**) due to an error about the coefficients $C$ (mistake about index $m$). I can't write the general form of ${\overline{F}}_{m}{\left( k_{m} \right)}$ more clearly, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

*Cleaning a little bit notations*

The first range is a bit larger
$$F{(k) = {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{k}{\cos(n)}}}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\csc \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \sin
   \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} \left(\csc \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+1\right)\leq F(k) \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(\csc \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)$$

$$\overline F(k) = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n = 1}^{k} \left( k - n + 1\right) \,\cos(n,$$

$$\overline F(k) = \frac{1}{4} \csc ^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\cos (1)-\cos (k+1)}{k}\right)-\frac 12$$